# running a program over x amount of times

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that calls a function (roll die() which rolls a die 1000 times and counts on a list [1,2,3,4,5,6] so an outcome might be [100,200,100,300,200,100]) and tells it to run it x amount of times.  It seems my code is printing it over and over again x times

```
#simulate rolling a six-sided die multiple tiems, and tabulate the results using a list
import random  #import from the library random so you can generate a random int
def rollDie(): 
    #have 6 variables and set the counter that equals 0
    one = 0  
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0
    six = 0
    #use a for loop to code how many times you want it to run
    for i in range(0,1000):
        #generate a random integer between 1 and 6
        flip = int(random.randint(1,6))
        # the flip variable is the the number you rolled each time
        #Every number has its own counter
        #if the flip is equal to the corresponding number, add one
        if flip == 1:
            one = one + 1
        elif flip == 2:
            two = two + 1
        elif flip == 3:
            three = three + 1
        elif flip == 4:
            four = four + 1
        elif flip == 5:
            five = five + 1
        elif flip == 6:
            six = six + 1
        #return the new variables as a list
    return [one,two,three,four,five,six]
```

the new function that I am having problems with is:

```
def simulateRolls(value):
    multipleGames = rollDie() * value
    return multipleGames
```

I would like to see a result like this if you typed in 4 for value

```
[100,300,200,100,100,200]
[200,300,200,100,100,100]
[100,100,100,300,200,200]
[100,100,200,300,200,100]
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You can get what you want like this:

```
def simulateRolls(value):
    multipleGames = [rollDie() for _ in range(value)]
    return multipleGames
```

By the way, your original function seems to work perfectly fine, but if you're interested, you can remove some redundancy like this:

```
def rollDie(): 
    #have 6 variables and set the counter that equals 0
    results = [0] * 6

    #use a for loop to code how many times you want it to run
    for i in range(0,1000):
        #generate a random integer between 1 and 6
        flip = int(random.randint(1,6))
        # the flip variable is the the number you rolled each time
        results[flip - 1] += 1

    return results
```

Comment: thank you for your help. is it possible if you could use a while loop instead of a for loop?

Comment: the `for` loop makes sense. Why use a `while` loop?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
multipleGames = rollDie() * value
```

will evaluate `rollDie()` once and multiply the result by `value`.

To instead repeat the call `value` times do this.

```
return [rollDie() for i in xrange(value)]
```

You can also simplify your rollDie function by working with a list throughout

```
import random  #import from the library random so you can generate a random int
def rollDie(): 
    result = [0] * 6
    for i in range(0,1000):
        result[random.randint(0,5)] += 1
    return result
```